# How do I obtain this expression for the Taylor series of$\frac{z^2}{\sin ^2(z)}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, riemann-zeta

Reading about Complex Analysis, I came across the following:

Consider first the representation $\frac{\pi ^2}{\sin ^2(\pi z)}=\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac{1} {(z+n)^2}$, which applies for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\backslash \mathbb{Z}$.

For $|z|<\pi$, we can obtain the following expression for the Taylor series of $\frac{z^2}{\sin^2(z)}$:

$\frac{z^2}{\sin^2(z)}=1+2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(2m-1)\frac{\zeta (2m)}{\pi^{2m}}z^{2m}$

where $\zeta(z) =\sum \frac{1}{n^z}$. This expression can then be used to obtain the values $\zeta (2)$ and $\zeta (4)$.

My question is, how is the expression for the Taylor series obtained? I am not able to obtain it from the representation for $\frac{\pi ^2}{\sin ^2(\pi z)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we can write

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}\frac1{(z+n\pi)^2}&=\frac1{z^2}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac1{(z+n\pi)^2}+\frac1{(z-n\pi)^2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac1{z^2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^2+(n\pi)^2}{(z^2-(n\pi)^2)^2}\\\\
&=\frac1{z^2}+\frac2{z^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^\infty (2m-1)(z/n\pi)^{2m}\\\\
&=\frac1{z^2}+\frac2{z^2} \sum_{m=1}^\infty (2m-1) \frac{\zeta(2m)}{\pi^{2m}}z^{2m}
\end{align}$$

Can you finsish now?

Comment: Yes! This clears everything. Thank you kindly.

Comment: @SiegmeyerofCatarina Pleased to hear.  And you're welcome.  My pleasure.